# How to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+2x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I want to calculate the following integral: $$I:=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\underbrace{\frac{x^2+2x}{x^4+x^2+1}}_{=:f(x)}dx$$ Of course, I could try to determine $\int f(x)\;dx$ in terms of integration by parts. However, I don't think that's the way one should do this. So, what's the trick to calculate $I$?

Comment: Since $2x/(x^4+x^2+1)$ is an odd function it integrates to zero. Now can you work with $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1} dx?$$

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition would help.

Comment: @David H I realised that & removed it (sorry all)

Comment: First factor the denominator into something like $x^4 + x^2 + 1 = (x^2 + ax + 1)(x^2 + bx + 1)$. You will have to find $a$ and $b$. Then use partial fractions. The integrand will be of the form $$\frac{x^2 + x}{(x^2 + ax + 1)(x^2 + bx + 1)} = \frac{Ax + B}{x^2 + ax + 1} + \frac{Cx + D}{x^2 + bx + 1}$$ and you will have to find  $A,B,C,D$ next. After that it's two standard integrals.

Comment: $$\frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}=\frac{x}{2 \left(x^2-x+1\right)}-\frac{x}{2 \left(x^2+x+1\right)}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $$\frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\frac{x}{x^2-x+1}-\frac{x}{x^2+x+1}\right\}$$

Comment: 1 + x^2 + x^4 = (x^6 - 1)/(x^2 - 1), so you need to integrate (x^2 -1)x^2/(x^6 - 1). It's easy to locate the poles, so applying the resudue theorem is easy. If you want to do it using partial fractions, then that's also easy by expanding around the four poles and adding up the singular parts of the Laurent expansions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice $$\frac{x^2+2x}{\color{blue}{x^4+x^2+1}}
= \frac{x(x+2)}{\color{blue}{(x^2+1)^2-x^2}} =
\frac12\left(\frac{x+2}{x^2-x+1} - \frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}\right)\\
= \frac12\left(\frac{(x-\frac12)+\frac52}{(x-\frac12)^2+\frac34}
- \frac{(x+\frac12)+\frac32}{(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34}
\right)
$$
Plug this into original integral will split it into two pieces.
Change variables to $y = x \mp \frac12$ for the two new integrals.
After throwing away terms that will get cancel out due to symmetry, i.e. the $y$ term in the numerators, we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2+2x}{x^4+x^2+1}
=\frac12\left(\frac52-\frac32\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dy}{y^2+\frac34} =
\frac12\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\frac34}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Very nice solution!!! Voteup!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the integral is:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}\,dx=2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}\,dx\,\,\,(*)$$
With the change of variables $x\mapsto 1/x$, 
$$I=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4+x^2+1}\,dx\,\,\,\,\,\,(**)$$
Add $(*)$ and $(**)$ i.e
$$2I=2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}\,dx \Rightarrow I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+1}\,dx$$
Rewrite the denominator as $\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2+3$ and use the substitution $x-\dfrac{1}{x}=t$,
$$\Rightarrow I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^2+3}=\boxed{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}$$

Comment: That's a nifty way to solve this integral. +1

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+2x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+2x}{x^4+x^2+1}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+2x}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=2\pi i\sum_{\Im x_i>0} \text{Res}(f(x);x_i)$$
$$x_i=\left\{\sqrt[3]{-1},(-1)^{2/3}\right\}$$
so we get $$\left\{\frac{1}{12} \left(3-5 i \sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{4} i \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)\right\}$$ as two residues.
$$
\therefore 2\pi i*-\frac{i}{2 \sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}
$$